# The way to find what URLs my computer is requesting

Tags: networking, ubuntu

For example, I enter google.com as the URL in browser. It "goes to resolve" the name. Another application may try to connect to a URL without I know. I need to track what's happening in my computer. For some reason, I need this.
Is there a way?
I tried WireShark, but it can't concentrate on an application and it gets work hard to find what I want between so many packets.
The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: not sure if Network Monitor can meet your requirement, there are many filter options you can use to find what information you would like to check. https://www.microsoft.com/en-sg/download/details.aspx?id=4865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try TCPview for Linux. I haven't used it on Ubuntu, windows version is good. Give the linux version a try. The link is here.
https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpview-for-linux/

Comment: It worked, although not exactly as I expected. My ideal is to "log" all ip's the app has had connection with, but it seems that it shows only the ip's it has connection with at the moment and you may lose some if you are slow in tracking.

Answer (score 2):

If you are mainly interested in which domains your computer is accessing then you might consider using [Pi-hole](https://pi-hole.net) as your DNS server.

As well as the benefits of blocking many undesirable domains, Pi-hole provides a web-based control panel with plenty of reports/logs as to which domains have been requested/blocked/allowed.

One installation of Pi-hole on your network can provide the same logging/blocking to any devices (computers, TVs, etc) which you configure to use the Pi-hole machine for DNS.

Comment: thanks. is it an application which may be installed in my currently used ubuntu? or it should be setup on a separate server?

Comment: I think you can choose either way. I've only tried it on a separate machine. It doesn't require a lot of processing power so many people choose to re-use an old PC/laptop or something like a Raspberry Pi as a dedicated Pi-hole server.

Comment: Thank you. I've had no time to examine it. I'll update vote your answer as the answer as soon as I do. Thank you very much.

Comment: I can't install it. It hangs on [i] Existing PHP installation detected : PHP version 7.4.3

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in only the activities of the active tab of your browser, you can use the developer tools feature that comes with most modern browsers.

if you instead interested in knowing the whole browser activities, you can use something like the [ZAP](https://owasp.org/www-project-zap/) proxy. after your get it up and set it as proxy of your browser, it can intercept all requests your browser send and responses it get.

in case you meant to know ALL activities of your browser, not just the HTTP stuff, you can use `perf` or `ftrace` or even the latest `bpftrace` tool to see all function calls it makes and files it tried to access.

Comment: Activities of browser is not meant. It's a separate application.
Thanks for the info.